# Progress Bar with Specific Value

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to design and implement a progress bar. But i have some problems.

My progress bar **layout** like this

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress1"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:maxHeight="5sp"
    android:progress="45" />
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
ProgressBar pb1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress1);
```

My problem is about `android:max`. Is there a way to change it with user's choice. For example user maybe wants to set 1500 for max value. I want to do it with plain text. (User must enter his/her value to plain text).

How can i implement it on java side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ProgressBar pb1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress1);
pb1.setMax(1500);
```

You can take the value from the user in an `EditText`, and the convert it to an `int` from a `String` using `Integer.parseInt()`. Then simply pass that `int` to the `setMax()` method to change the maximum value.

Comment: Solution is ok, thank a lot. But if i have 2 activites, assume EditText in ActivityA and ProgressBar in ActivityB. What it the approach?

Comment: @hakiko Take the input in ActivitA, and pass it as an Intent Extra to ActivityB. Then retrieve it and set it using setMax().